# Bitbucket : The requested URL returned error: 402

Tags: android, git, android-studio, bitbucket

I changed password on bitbucket, and now Android Studio can't make push error on Event Log:

```
Push failed: Failed with error: fatal: unable to access 'https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git/': The requested URL returned error: 402
```

How to solve it?

Comment: **402 Payment Required:** 
Reserved for future use. The original intention was that this code might be used as part of some form of digital cash or micropayment scheme, but that has not happened, and this code is not usually used. Google Developers API uses this status if a particular developer has exceeded the daily limit on requests

Comment: Have you updated your Bitbucket password in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me and the fix was to remove some users from my repositories.
Bitbucket's free plan comes with unlimited private repos so, deleting your repos may not have any effect. However, you can only add a maximum of 5 users with the free plan.

Answer (score 0):

This server response is due to the fact that you have exceeded the free limit for Bitbucket. You have two options:

1. Upgrade your Bitbucket server license
2. Delete some old repos you don't need anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was delete user that dont have access in repo.

Answer (score 0):

```
// make sure your git credentials are up-to-date with your new password

git config --global credential.helper wincred  // For Windows

git config --global credential.helper cache    // For macOS & Linux
```

---

```
git remote -v // your remote repo is updated with your new password

// if your url contain your old username & password update it using

git remote set-url origin https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

---

```
// re-enter your credentials
```